# Can assumptions made during calculation of ka of buffer solutions be justified?

Tags: equilibrium

We make many assumptions in sciences which are not always true but as they make little difference we ignore them for simplicity. But today I have decided that I can no longer be lured into using expression of $K_{a}$ and $K_{w}$ by assumptions which I deem to make a significant difference.

1. We say that $[H_{2}O]$ is constant. Why I think it is not justified?
   $$\ce{H2O + HCL <=> H3O+ + Cl-}$$
   $[H_{2}O]$ is almost $ 55.6 \:\mathrm{mol\:dm^-3}{}$.
   At around $20^{o}C$ $20\:\mathrm{mol}$ of $HCl_{aq}$ can be dissolved. Let's say we dissolve $20 \:\mathrm{mol}$ of $HCl$ and try to find it's **WE ASSUME** that % disassociation of water is $100 \%$. So we must take $[HCl]\approx0$ that means that $20\:\mathrm{mol}$ of $H_{2}O$ has reacted and $[H_{2}O]$ is no longer a constant but has rather changed to $35.6\mathrm{mol}$.
   So this expression can no longer be used. $$K_{a}=\frac{[H_{3}O^{+}].[Cl^{-}]} {[HCl]}=K_{c}.[H_{2}O]$$
   ***Note:*** you might point out that $K_{a}$ is not used for strong acids but I just used $HCl$ as an example but make my point easier to explain.
2. Assumption made about concentrations when calculating $Ka$ of buffer solutions.
   $$CH_{3}COOH_{aq} \rightleftharpoons CH_{3}COO^{-}_{aq} + H^{+}_{aq}$$
   We have added $CH_{3}COONa$  to make a buffer solution.
   $$CH_{3}COONa_{aq} \rightarrow CH_{3}COO^{-}_{aq} + Na^{+}_{aq}$$
   So,
   $$[CH_{3}COO^{-}]_{total}=[CH_{3}COO^{-}]_{CH_{3}COONa} + [CH_{3}COO^{-}]_{CH_{3}COOH}$$
   $$[CH_{3}COO^{-}]_{CH_{3}COOH} = [H^{+}_{aq}]$$
   **BUT WE ASSUME** that $[CH_{3}COO^{-}]_{total}=[CH_{3}COO^{-}]_{CH_{3}COONa}$ because we say $[CH_{3}COO^{-}]_{CH_{3}COOH}$ is negligible yet we include [$H_{aq}^{+}]$ in the expression which has same value as $[CH_{3}COO^{-}]_{CH_{3}COOH}$. Same value is considered negligible at one place and not negligible at another in the same expression. How is that justified?

Comment: ThThis might help:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henderson%E2%80%93Hasselbalch_equation#Derivation  Think about how large the value of the acetate from sodium acetate is compared to the value of acetate from acetic acid.

Comment: You neglected that Ka and Kw are only meaningful when the concentration is low (usually below 1 M). For HCl, you have a solution near 12 M. In the second case, as explained below, it is ignored because it make less than 0.1% difference in the calculation (sometimes it would make the calculation very difficult to solve if it was not ignored).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your first question, $[\ce {H2O}]$ is constant because the square brackets indicate a concentration. Concentration is the number of moles of the solute on the volume of the solvent.

Except in this case, water *is* the solvent. So the concentration will always be constant, since the volume is proportional to the number of moles.

Besides, while dealing with the law of mass action, for liquids we don't take *concentration*, we take *activity*. Which is approximately one for water.

As for your second question, we basically have the following product:

$$\ce{([CH3COO- ]_{CH3COOH} + [CH3COO- ]_{CH3COONa})[H+ ]}$$

which can be rewritten as $(a + b)b$, where $b << a$. Let's say $a$ was $1$ and $b$ was $0.0001$.

The actual value of the expression is $1.0001\times 10^{-4}$. Neglecting only the first $b$ will give $1\times 10^{-4}$, which is not too much different.

Neglecting only the second $b$ will give $1.0001$, and neglecting both will give $1$. Both of these answers are very wrong.

When a small number is added to a large one, the small number can be ignored. But not when it is multiplied.

Comment: The first part failed to explain the reason behind concentration of water being constant. The reason I had figured out and written in the answer below and your answer is being marked for it explains second part beautifully. For this reason first part had to be removed.

Comment: @Suchal I clarified it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part I was forgetting this simple this:
$$[H_{2}O]=\frac{n(H_{2}O)}{Volume_{H_{2}O}} mol.dm^{-3}$$
So as the $n(H_{2}O)$ will decrease the $Volume_{H_{2}O}$ will decrease too making $[H_{2}O]$ a constant.
The second part have been answered by ManishEarth.